# Delete S3 Bucket With Deny All Policy And VPC Condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm on the process of exploring `VPC Enpoints` and I've created a problem for myself. In my process using `cloudformation` I've spawned a bucket with the following `bucket policy`:

```
ArtifactBucketPolicy:
  Description: Setting Amazon S3 bucket policy for AWS CodePipeline access
  Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  Properties:
    Bucket: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
    PolicyDocument:
      Id: SSEAndSSLPolicy
      Statement:
      - Action: s3:*
        Condition:
          StringNotEquals:
            aws:SourceVpce:
              Fn::ImportValue:
                !Sub project-03:dev:${AWS::Region}:VPC:ID
        Effect: Deny
        Principal: '*'
        Resource:
        - !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:s3:::${ArtifactsBucket}'
        - !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:s3:::${ArtifactsBucket}/*'
        Sid: VPCe
      Version: 2012-10-17
```

and now I'm trying to delete the bucket but even as an admin or root I cannot access the bucket to change the policy or do anything to it.

I've attempted to launch an EC2 in both the private and public subnet with a full admin role attached to it, and ran the following commands:

```
aws s3 rm s3://BUCKET_NAME/
aws s3api delete-bucket --bucket BUCKET_NAME
```

but I get the following error

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

I've also made sure that the `VPC Endpoint` is being used since when I run

```
sudo traceroute -n -T -p 443 s3.amazonaws.com
```

and outputs

```
traceroute to s3.amazonaws.com (52.216.130.45), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  * * *
2  * * *
3  * * *
4  * * *
5  * * *
6  * * *
7  52.216.130.45  0.662 ms  0.848 ms  0.723 ms
```

which I believe to mean that the endpoint is being used.

I've logged into the ec2 instances using session manager, and through ssh but still no luck.

Question:

Is there any way for me to delete this bucket?

Comment: Can you just modify the bucket policy first?

Comment: Is it S3 Interface endpoint of S3 gateway endpoint? How did you set them up? Do they even work? Also did you try these [steps](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access/)?

Comment: If you are root (not an admin user - it has to be the actual root account) and making the change to the policy it should go through. When you are making explicit deny policies, it's helpful to test based on a deny of an easily reversible permission like s3:delete, so that if your scope or other assumptions don't work out you can easily revert.

Comment: @Marcin, thank you that solved the issue.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, to solution was obtained by following AWS guidlines:

- [I accidentally denied everyone access to my Amazon S3 bucket. How do I regain access?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access/)